# ADF Power query Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory, powerquery

I am trying to use the Power Query feature in ADF. As more well versed in SQL than M language, is it possible to use native SQL query in ADF Power query to retrieve data from source database ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Query activity which allows you to use SQL query for source database.

> The **Power Query activity** allows you to build and execute Power Query
> mash-ups to execute data wrangling at scale in a Data Factory
> pipeline. You can create a new Power Query mash-up from the New
> resources menu option or by adding a Power Activity to your pipeline.

Refer: [Data Wrangling with Power Query in Azure Data Factory](https://www.sqlshack.com/data-wrangling-with-power-query-in-azure-data-factory/)

Comment: yeah, but can we use sql like 'select * from ...' kind of query from power query on ADF. We have this option if we use Sql.Database  to connect source and get data using native sql from power bi desktop